# Is there a commandline flag to set PYTHONHOME?

Tags: python, android

I'm attempting to run python on a system that doesn't allow me to set environment variables.  Is there a commandline flag to python that will set PYTHONHOME?  I looked here: http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/inst/search-path.html but didn't see anything.

So, hopefully something like this:

```
python -magical_path_flag /my/python/install test.py
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for the responses everyone.  I'm embarrassed to say I actually meant PYTHONHOME, not PYTHONPATH.  (That's what I deserve for asking a question at 1:30 AM.)  I've edited my quesiton.

Here's some more info.  I'm trying to get python running on Android.  I can run python -V no problem, but if I try and execute a script, I get:

```
I/ControlActivity(18340): Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
I/ControlActivity(18340): Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
```

Unfortunately when using the ProcessBuilder and changing the environment variables on Android, it says that they're not modifiable and throws an exception.  I'm able to pass all the command line flags I want, so I was hoping I could set PYTHONHOME that way.

I've tried creating a wrapping shell script which exports PYTHONHOME and then calls python but that didn't work.  (Got the same error as before.)

Thanks,

Gabe

Comment: "a system" isn't very helpful. Try telling us *what* system.

Answer (score 5):

You could simply set it in your script -- `sys.path` is a regular, modifiable list. Something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/libraries")
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

In UNIXy shells, you can set an environment variable just for the duration of one command by prepending the command with the environment variable setting:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/my/python/install python test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other answers suit you, you can write a wrapper script that temporarily sets the environment variable then exec's your other script. For example:

```
python mywrapper.py -magical_path_flag /my/python/install test.py
```